# What programming language or components is used with ESET NOD32 v4?

Tags: user-interface, interface, nod32

I really like the interface of ESET NOD32 antivirus program and I would like to know with what is this done and what components are used?

http://coolmaliya-gifts.comli.com/images/nod32-3-1.jpg

Answer (score 2):

If you have Spy++ around somewhere (comes with Visual Studio) you could look what window classes are used for the controls. This may give hints. Other than that, I doubt those are ready-made stock controls and they are likely self-drawn.